# Ubuntu 16.04 - Error Installing Apache2 & Opencpu-server

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, opencpu

I'm stuck. I try to install apache, opencpu-server, R but all fails to:

```
opencpu-server is already the newest version (2.0.3-xenial10).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up libapache2-mod-apreq2 (2.13-4ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-apreq2 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up libapache2-mod-r-base (1.2.7-1) ...
dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-r-base (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of opencpu-server:
 opencpu-server depends on libapache2-mod-r-base (>= 1.2.5); however:
  Package libapache2-mod-r-base is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package opencpu-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 libapache2-mod-apreq2
 libapache2-mod-r-base
 opencpu-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried to do `sudo a2enmod R` but it says module does not exists. I'm not really good with linux servers. Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have package conflict for apache on your system, in particular `libapache2-mod-apreq2` which is a dependency of rapache. What do you see for:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-apreq2
```

I'm guessing you have been installing packages from other repositories or some system upgrade has not gone well. You might want to `apt-get purge` some packages. Also check that there are no sources in `/etc/apt/` that point to repositories from incorrect debian/ubuntu versions.

Comment: That command return error "subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1". 

There are only xenials in sources.list. 

How do I know what should I purge?

Comment: I got a bit further removing 2 packages, but now I get: Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘unix’

Comment: Try full resintall: `sudo apt-get remove --purge opencpu-*` and then `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install opencpu-server`.

Comment: This worked {sudo apt-get remove --purge opencpu-*}. Thanks! :)